# Resizing images to fit a Div's restrictions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I've put together a simple grid gallery using Freewall found here http://vnjs.net/www/project/freewall/.

The gallery is working fine, but I'm having trouble getting images to resize to the div, I've tried using object-fit, which didn't seem to make a different && also tried img-responsive. Which also didn't work. I've added the code below

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div id="freewall" class="free-wall"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var temp = "<div class='cell img-responsive' style='width:{width}px; height: {height}px; background-image: url(img/gallery/test/{index}.jpg);'></div>";
        var w = 400, h = 400, html = '', limitItem = 49;
        for (var i = 0; i < limitItem; ++i) {
            html += temp.replace(/\{height\}/g, h).replace(/\{width\}/g, w).replace("{index}", i + 1);
        }
        $("#freewall").html(html);

        var wall = new Freewall("#freewall");
        wall.reset({
            selector: '.cell',
            animate: true,
            cellW: 400,
            cellH: 400,
            onResize: function() {
                wall.refresh();
            }
        });
        wall.fitWidth();
        // for scroll bar appear;
        $(window).trigger("resize");
    </script>
```

CSS

```
.free-wall {
    margin: 15px;
    object-fit: scale-down;
}
```

And a screenshot so you can see the issue
[image]
I don't mind if I have to use Jquery or Javascript, but image scaling has been an issue for me for some time, if anyone can provide a robust solution that can be applied to images that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your styles add `background-size: cover;` and it'd resize to div's width & height always like below

```
var temp = "<div class='cell img-responsive' style='width:{width}px; height: {height}px; background-image: url(img/gallery/test/{index}.jpg);background-size: cover;'></div>";
```